# Transmit and Read Image using Web Socket

Tags: java, html, sockets, websocket

I am using jWebSocket to transmit messages between my JavaSE client and the Browser.

Now I want to transmit an Image using socket. Currently I am using

getTokenServer().sendPacket(wsc, wsPacket);

to transmit the messages.

How could I modify it to transmit images.

Also, how could i view the images transmitted through web socket in my browser.

Comment: I tried many variations for creating a WebServerPacket(wsPacket) from an image. But all resulted in errors. And the java doc for jWebSocket too is incomplete. So couldnt get any help there.

Comment: Then try to post the code you have tried, and what error you get. You have to be specific if you want to increase the chance of getting a useful answer on this site.

Comment: Thnx for dat, I'll try and do dat asap.